# Use of require(lib) versus <script> in Electron apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, electron

I don't have a handle on when to use `require('jslib')` versus `<script src=""></script>` in Electron content pages (e.g. index.html). With jQuery, I discovered that it needs to be loaded as follows:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js');</script>
```

I need to start using some other libraries (e.g. Handlebars, ds3.js, Bootstrap, etc.) and I am not sure if I should be loading those with the `<script>` tag or if I should `require` them.

Comment: It all depends on the library. If the library can be exposed through CommonJS (`module.exports = ...`) then you will have to `require` it. Otherwise, a simple `<script src="..."></script>` will do.

Comment: @MikeC It appears that `require` works even if a JS script file does not utilize CommonJS. Does that mean that I can generally use `require` in place of `<script src="..."></script>`? Even though I ask that question, I think I should be looking inside a JS file to determine when to use one or the other.

Comment: In general, you could get away with that, yes.

Comment: @MikeCluck Why do you say _you will have to require it_ if it is exposed through CommonJS? Shouldn't `<script src="..."></script>` still work? And how come `require` works in general then? This question deserves an answer...

Answer (score 4):

Some libraries only expose their variables through a CommonJS interface. Others, like jQuery, will also expose them as global variables.

The reason you can't just do `<script src="..."></script>` for a library that only exposes through CommonJS is that it won't bind to the global space.

**Binding with CommonJS**

```
module.exports = myLibrary;
```

**Bindings to the global scope**

```
window.myLibrary = myLibrary;
```

If a library only does the former then you will not be able to access the value without using `require`. If a library only does the latter, then you will *not* be able to access it with `require` in the sense of `const myLibrary = require('my-library')`

In general, it's a better idea to use CommonJS over global variables. Adding variables to the global scope can lead to name collisions and directly loading in your dependencies makes it easier for the next person to tell where that dependency came from. Not to mention, CommonJS allows static analysis tools to work better so you're more likely to get relevant code completions and type definitions.

Using the example of jQuery, it would be better to use it like this.

```
// main.js
const $ = require('./js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js');
// could also be done like this if you install it as a Node dependency
// const $ = require('jquery');

$(document).ready(...);
```

---

```
<!-- index.html -->
...
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

**TL;DR**

Use `require('my-library')` when possible, load them as globals when it is not.

Comment: This is an excellent post but I don't think it addresses the elephant in the room that is why is `require` available at all in an Electron app? In any normal web apps, `require` does not exist and has to be polyfilled by using a module loader/bundler. In an Electron app, the native `require` is simply made available to you.

Comment: @customcommander I didn't think that was an elephant since all of the Electron documentation shows that it gives you access to modules in the same way as Node i.e., via CommonJS format.

Comment: Ok fair enough, you may be right. I just thought that it was worth mentioning nonetheless since this question specifically mentions an Electron context. Thanks for you clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Before module bundlers, libraries would have to be imported either via a `<script>` tag or via module loaders such as [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/).

Now it's easier to assume a CommonJS environment and get everything through a module bundler which will expose a `require` function for you in a browser context.

All of this is not necessary in the context of an Electron app:

> In normal browsers, web pages usually run in a sandboxed environment and are not allowed access to native resources. Electron users, however, have the power to use Node.js APIs in web pages allowing lower level operating system interactions.

*Cf. [renderer process](https://electronjs.org/docs/glossary#renderer-process)*

That means that the native Node.js `require` function (amongst other things) is available in your renderer process!

Here's a simple Electron app to prove it:

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "the-answer": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

My `main.js`: (the main process)

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

My `index.html`: (the renderer process)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      const os = require('os'); // Standard Node.js module
      const answer= require('the-answer'); // An NPM package that returns the answer to everything.
    </script>
    <button onclick="alert(os.platform())">YOUR PLATFORM</button>
    <button onclick="alert(answer)">THE ANSWER</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**So which method should you use?**

Electron exposes the native Node.js `require` function. It would be a shame not to leverage this: you would be able to require packages by their names and split your code into reusable modules as you would do in any Node.js apps.

Comment: This doesn't explain why they would use `require` over a script tag or vice versa.

Comment: Fair. I provided some additional information. However considering that the OP mentions Electron, it's actually important to mention that the native `require` function is available and that it hasn't been provided by some module loader or bundler.

Comment: Further edited this to clarify my position on which methods to use.