# require is not defined in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to build a web-desktop application using ElectronJs and AngularJS, so I wrote my code and everything worked fine when I start my desktop application, but in the browser, I have a problem - I have an undefined method.

Here is the line where I am having a problem :

```
const electron = require('electron')
```

Everything works fine as I said when I tap my command :

```
electron .
```

But when I open my file index.html in my browser I get this error in my console

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I tried some solutions like importing 'require.js' but nothing is working.

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
```

But I get another error which is :

```
Error: Module name "electron" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

Comment: isn't Electron in NodeJS

Comment: Yes.. But how is that gonna help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: I don't think I've downvoted your question, I've just happened to realize that your question was not answered and that this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined was, so I thought I'd mark yours as a duplicate of to help you, and other people, find the right answer. I'm sorry if I offended you @TaouBen , but that was certainly not my intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the require calls in an if block and check if require is defined:

```
if (typeof require === 'function') {
    const electron = require('electron')
}
```

You don't want to be requiring electron (or any other Node modules) if you're running in a browser anyway.