# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined - Electron js

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm using electron for the first time at the same time as js and node, I'm trying to make an application for hobby and knowledge.
I'm facing a problem when implementing my script to open external links.

I've been using the [doc](https://electronjs.org/docs) to fix the problem, but I haven't seen anything to help me with that problem.

My **ex-links.js**

```py
const electron = require("electron");
const { shell } = electron;
const exLinkBtn = document.getElementById("open-ex-link");
exLinkBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  shell.openExternal("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifXalt3MJtM");
});
```

I've already tried to place the slider.html inside index.html and yet I still get that error, so I left it as I currently have it inside an iframe.

```html
<iframe src="slider.html" frameborder=0 width="1180" height="728" style="padding-left:198.5px;"></iframe>
```

I expect that by clicking the open-ex-link button it will open the link in the default browser.

Comment: The first thing that looks strange to me is that this looks like your client side app. In which case, I'm not 100% sure `require` will work in the browser. Have you tried using `import` instead?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241 too

Comment: @mwilson I'm trying to make it just in the client side , does it affect ? , this is my [main.js](https://pastebin.com/EeZ04KTQ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

The default `nodeIntegration` value is `false`. So you can set it to `true` to solve the issue.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
});
```

But, `nodeIntegration: true` is a security risk when you are executing some untrusted remote code on your application. For example, when your application opens up a third party webpage, it would be a security risk because the third party webpage will have access to node runtime and can run  malicious code on the user's filesystem. So it makes sense to set `nodeIntegration: false` which is the default now.

You can use preload scripts as they have access to `require` and other Node.js features.

The index.js would be like:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
  }
})
```

The preload.js would be like:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');

let currentWindow = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

window.closeCurrentWindow = function(){
  currentWindow.close();
}
```