# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, requirejs

I am trying and failing to connect to a MySQL database in Electron.  When I run the program with `npm start`, I get this error in the console:

[image: electron]

I was told to make changes to my code and I made them but nothing.  I downloaded that module called bundlee but it didn't work either and I don't know if I used it correctly.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you

Comment: what version of electron?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that `nodeIntegration` is set to `false` (which is the default) in your `BrowserWindow` `webPreferences`.

Try setting up your browser window with something like this:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, 
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    } 
})
```