# electron.js title bar problem: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at titleBarStuff.js:1

Tags: javascript, electron

Hi everyone I've got this problem:
I'm making a native code editor with electron.js following a tutorial on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQLSBva6BkQ&list=PLTHrJfrjCyJAxErpBW4B1IXFU3tpn61r6&index=4
In lesson 4 he teaches you how to make a custom frame/titlebar.

in the main page I wrote this:
`<script src="js/titleBarStuff.js"></script>`

in titleBarStuff.js I wrote this:

> `const remote = require("electron").remote; //I get the error at this line`
>
> `var minimize = document.getElementById('minimize');`
> `var maximize = document.getElementById('maximize');`
> `var quit = document.getElementById('quit');`
>
> `minimize.addEventListener("click", minimizeApp);`
> `maximize.addEventListener("click", maximizeApp);`
> `quit.addEventListener("click", quitApp);`
>
> `function minimizeApp(){`
> `console.log("app min")`
> `remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();`
> `}`
>
> `function maximizeApp(){`
> `remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().maximize();`
> `}`
>
> `function quitApp(){`
> `remote.BrowserWindow.getCurrentWindow.close();`
> `}`
>
> `function createWindow(){`
>
> `win = new BrowserWindow({`
>
> `widht:900,`
> `height:800,`
>  `minHeight:650,`
>  `minWidth:600,`
> `frame:false,`
>
> `webPreferences: {`
>  `nodeIntegration: true`
>  `}`
> `})`
> `}`

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at titleBarStuff.js:1
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: no, it does not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following object to your main.js file inside the createWindow function.

```js
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,-+

}
```

Comment: Please, don't include code as image. Can you [edit] your answer?