# How to import chessboard js in my electron project

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to electron and javascript. I want to use the library [chesboardjs](https://chessboardjs.com/)

on their website it says it is quite simple just 2 lines of code to display the board. I installed it using `npm install -save @chrisoakman/chessboardjs` now I want to use it but I have no idea how to import it. I don't see anything about that on the website.

Comment: Their website assumes that you have a basic understanding of imports in general, or as specified in the Electron docs. This isn't something specific to that library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671803/how-to-use-import-or-require-in-electron

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use import or require in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671803/how-to-use-import-or-require-in-electron)

Comment: I tried this ```import { Chessboard } from "./node_modules/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.js";```but I am getting this error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.js' does not provide an export named 'Chessboard'```

Comment: Is that the file I should actually import BTW? It said nowhere I just assumed.