# How to get node into other .js files other than index.js in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to get node into other .js files, other than just index.js. I can only run require() in index.js, and that's not useful when trying to use  electron-prompt. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, providing the specific packages you want to use might allow for a more specific fix, however, as a general overview.

In electron you can change the node integration settings when you create your browser window using the code block below. This isn't recommended as it poses a security risk when running remote code. If you don't care about security(which you should) you can go ahead and use this.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
});
```

If you do care about security, I would check out the second answer to this post:
[Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448)