# __dirname not defined with: ipcRenderer.on(‘settings’, () => {

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, require, ipcrenderer

I first created a brand new vue.js project with @vue/cli :

vue create newproject

during the creation process, I chose typescipt option.

Then, I installed electron-builder plugin:

vue add electron-builder

executing yarn electron:serve the brand new app seems working :

[image]

But when I add these two lines :

ipcRenderer.on('settings', () => {
}

in Ipc.vue:

I get there error messages :
[image]

babel.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    //"module": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "mocha",
      "chai"
    ],
    "paths": {
     "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Environment Info:

```
System:
  OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
  CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
Binaries:
  Node: 14.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/npm
Browsers:
  Chrome: 84.0.4147.105
  Firefox: 79.0
npmPackages:
  @vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  1.0.0 
  @vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  1.1.2 
  @vue/babel-preset-app:  4.4.6 
  @vue/babel-preset-jsx:  1.1.2 
  @vue/babel-sugar-functional-vue:  1.1.2 
  @vue/babel-sugar-inject-h:  1.1.2 
  @vue/babel-sugar-v-model:  1.1.2 
  @vue/babel-sugar-v-on:  1.1.2
```

How to solve the problem?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Update 1)

Putting nodeIntegration: true in the createWindow() function I'm getting this new error message:

[image]

By the way, I would prefer, for security reasons, keep nodeIntegration: false
I tried to use a preload file as suggested here: [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined/55908510#5590851)
but with:

```
  nodeIntegration: false,
  contextIsolation: true,
  preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), "preload.js"),
```

I get this error message:

[image]

Update 2)

This is preload.js :

```
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

const path = require("path");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) =>    
func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

and in background.js I put :

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: false,
  contextIsolation: true,
  preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Update 3)

With just nodeIntegration: true, without preload:

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

With also preload:

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
}
```

I get this other error:

[image]

Update 4) preload.js  and background.js are in the same folder: src

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, "./preload.js"),
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

This is webpack.config.js :

```
import 'script-loader!./script.js';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: ['electron-renderer', 'electron-main', 'electron-
preload'],
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      chainWebpackMainProcess: config => {
        config.resolve.alias.set('jsbi', path.join(__dirname, 
    'node_modules/jsbi/dist/jsbi-cjs.js'));
      }
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/background.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'backend.js'
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js is correct or should I modify something here?

Comment: are you enabling the nodeintegration when you are creating the browserWindow?

Comment: @tpikachu Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to put nodeIntegration: true, but got other error messages. I updated my post with Update 1)

Comment: Have you set this under webPreference?

Comment: And make sure you are including `const path = require("path")` in your preload or renderer where you are using this

Comment: @tpikachu I added const path = require("path") to both background.js and preload.js files. But got errors. I updated my post with Update 2)

Comment: `nodeIntegration: false`?

Comment: @tpikachu I put also nodeIntegration: true, but got errors as well. I updated my post with Update 3)

Comment: There is no `preload.js` in your path

Comment: Idk how you configured your project structure but you need to make sure the preload.js is placed properly

Comment: Seems, it just works fine on your dev env but not in prod

Comment: I believe you are loading webpack dev server while developing but in production, you are loading the build `index.html` Am I right?

Comment: @tpikachu I just started developing in electron.js. So I'm far from being in production. I update my post with Update 4) with the error messages when I specify correctly the path to preload.js

Comment: @tpikachu I opened a new question, describing better the problem of loading the preload.js script : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269216/unable-to-load-preload-script-electron-js-ubuntu-18-04-4