# desktopCapturer example... how to make it work for specific application

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electron/electron_audio_and_video_capturing.htm

The first part of the tutorial worked fine... I can stream av from my pc camera and mic... into my electron app.  But now I'm trying to do is stream audio and video from a specific application running on my windows desktop via the desktopCapturer object.

**Problem**

I'm not getting any errors.  But the electron app's video html tag is not showing the stream from myappthatstreamsAV.

**Code**

I changed my index.html code to look like this: (just changed stuff inside the  tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>Audio and Video</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <video autoplay></video>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
        var desktopCapturer = require('electron').desktopCapturer;
        desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
        if (error) throw error
         desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
            if (error) throw error
            for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
               if (sources[i].name === 'myappthatstreamsAV') {
                  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
                     audio: true,
                     video: {
                        mandatory: {
                           chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                           chromeMediaSourceId: sources[i].id,
                           minWidth: 1280,
                           maxWidth: 1280,
                           minHeight: 720,
                           maxHeight: 720
                        }
                     }
                  }, handleStream, handleError)
                  return
               }
            }
         })

         function handleStream (stream) {
            document.querySelector('video').src = URL.createObjectURL(stream)
         }

         function handleError (e) {
            console.log(e)
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and the index.js looks like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

let win

// Set the path where recordings will be saved
app.setPath("userData", __dirname + "/saved_recordings")

function createWindow() {
   win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true
     }
   })
   win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
   }))
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I added some debug statements like this:

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
     var desktopCapturer = require('electron').desktopCapturer;
     console.log("1")
     console.log(desktopCapturer)
     desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
        console.log("2")
        if (error) throw error
        for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
           console.log((sources[i].name));
           console.log("3")
```

and basically, it executes only the first two console.logs:

```
     console.log("1")
     console.log(desktopCapturer)
```

It never gets to 2 or 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: @snwflk yes.  that allows me to define the variable.  But now the code isn't working.  I don't have any stream that appears in my electron app.  No errors.  Will update questions

Answer (score 0):

Changed my code to look like this:

```
     var desktopCapturer = require('electron').desktopCapturer;
     console.log("are you here?")
     console.log(desktopCapturer)

     desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
        for (const source of sources) {
           if (source.name === 'mystreamApp') {
              try {
              const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                 audio: true,
                 video: {
                    mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                    chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                    minWidth: 1280,
                    maxWidth: 1280,
                    minHeight: 720,
                    maxHeight: 720
                    }
                 }
              })
              handleStream(stream)
              } catch (e) {
              handleError(e)
              }
              return
           }
        }
        })

        function handleStream (stream) {
        const video = document.querySelector('video')
        video.srcObject = stream
        video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => video.play()
        }

        function handleError (e) {
        console.log(e)
        }
```

and now I see the video stream.
Audio is still not working.  But i'll open another question for that.