# Electron/Tedious: require("events") is not defined

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, tedious

I have a problem with tedious/webpack/node/electron? I'm not sure.

Steps to reproduce:

- `git clone https://github.com/codesbiome/electron-react-webpack-typescript-2020`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn add tedious`
- `yarn add @types/tedious`

then add following lines to `App.tsx` (or anywhere else, just all it):

```
    const connectToDb = (): Promise<Connection> => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const config = { // those data doesn't matter much
          authentication: {
            options: {
              userName: "sa", // update me
              password: "" // update me
            },
            type: "default"
          },
          server: "test_db@localhost", // update me
          options: {
            database: "test", //update me
            encrypt: true
          }
        };
      
        const connection = new Connection(config) // error is caused by this
        connection.connect()
      })
    }
    
    connectToDb().then(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('err: ', err);
    })
```

and following error occurs in console (`View -> Toggle Developer Tools`)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.events (index.js:140037)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:790)
    at fn (index.js:101)
    at Object../node_modules/tedious/lib/bulk-load.js (index.js:99091)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:790)
    at fn (index.js:101)
    at Object../node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js (index.js:110052)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:790)
    at fn (index.js:101)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:139704)
```

Clicking on first redirect from stacktrace showing error in this `module.exports = require("events")`, this is exactly the `require` that's the problem.

I tried to manipulate `webpack` settings a bit also tried enabling `nodeIntegration` and others, but without any result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2023.**

Due to security reasons this answer is no longer a good approach.

Take a look at:
[Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined/59888788#59888788)

**Original answer**

I figured it out.

Fix:
`main.tsx` -> `BrowserWindow` -> `webPreferences` and change `contextIsolation` to `false` and also `nodeIntegration` to `true`.

After changing it, require reference error gone.

Comment: This WORKS... BUT it shouldn't be done due to security risks. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888788/12139920 for more info.

Comment: @Jake_3H Thanks for the info, updated the answer.
PS. I needed this for private usage, so it still a valid solution for me.