# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined with EEL

Tags: python, node.js, electron, eel

I am Trying to run html page with electron + eel.

I have successfully loaded the webpage + eel.js.

My Problem is whenever I try to use require module in the javascript of the HTML page. it gives me the below:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

The sequence is, launching the webapp using runner.py ( eel.start ), then electron start

Also, if I set `mainWindow.loadFile('templates/index.html')` in main.js file, instead of `mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/index.html')`. the render just work fine and can handle electron window from main html javascript file. but eel is not loaded in this case.

If I tried the steps which in the guide. the electron html page opens normally with eel.js loaded up. but can not handle the electron window from html javascript file

runner.py

```
import eel
import eel.browsers

eel.init('templates')
eel.browsers.set_path('electron', 'node_modules/electron/dist/electron')
eel.start('index.html', mode='electron' , port=8000  ,host='localhost',disable_cache=True)
```

main.js:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // mainWindow.loadFile('templates/index.html')
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/index.html')
  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

html javascript:

```
function login_check(){
    var serverIP = document.getElementById('serverIP').value
    var Username = document.getElementById('usernameEntry').value
    var Password = document.getElementById('passwordEntry').value
    var RememberMe = document.getElementById('remember-me-checkbox').checked


    if(serverIP != "" && Username != "" && Password != ""){

        document.querySelector('.progress-bar-container-div').classList.add('active')
    }

    else{

        const window = require("electron").getCurrentWindow()


        alert("Required Fields are empty.")
        document.querySelector('.progress-bar-container-div').classList.remove('active')
        window.minimize();

    }
    

}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Second answer in dup target.

Comment: The Answer is recommending to add " nodeIntegration=true" which i already have done.

Comment: Could there a problem with node on the client you're testing? The First answer explains the problem, `require` is not supported  out of the box in client-side JS.

Comment: There's another duplicate, even better than the first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined/55908510#55908510 - they have more answers and the question is more specifically like yours. Second answer there discusses pre-loading scripts.

Comment: still no luck, I see the difference that, I am using EEL as the initiator. noting that when i replace mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/index.html') with mainWindow.loadFile('templates/index.html')  .. it works. but eel.js is not loaded