# Require is Not Defined ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

So basically, I have 2 javascript files, the main one and the renderer for my application, the renderer file doesnt recognize Require, so I can`t get any modules, and electron won't work, can someone please help me fix this?

here is the code:

```
//Buttons

const videoElement = document.querySelector('video')
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn')
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn')
const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn')

const {desktopCapturer, remote} = require('electron');
const { Menu} = remote;

async function getVideoSources() {

const inputSources  = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window','screen']
});

const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map(source => {
        return {
            label: source.name,
            click: () => selectSource(source)
        }
    })

    
)
videoOptionsMenu.popup()


}

videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources();
```

Comment: Have you tried import instead?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: import { desktopCapturer, remote} from 'electron';

Comment: new error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Then can you please see if this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined

Comment: nope, no luck, couldnt find a fix

Comment: did you add nodeIntegration true in your electron main file

Comment: its fixed now, i dont know what the issue was, but I re-wrote the code and now it works, thanks for trying to answer it tho :)