# How do I use require() when building a webpack-based svelte app with Electron?

Tags: webpack, electron, svelte

I am attempting to call `require('electron')` from a .svelte file.  It is not defined.  I am using webpack with `target: 'electron-renderer`.

How do I include or require node modules from my electron renderer thread?

Comment: try `import electron from 'electron';` to see if it works

Answer (score 2):

I've written about this [in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined/59888788#59888788), so you may want to look there. The answer is not using svelte, but can be ported.

#### Brief summary

Electron apps *used* to include and recommend using `require` in the renderer process. This, however leads to security problems so the team has been slowly transitioning *away* from this. The *new* and better way is to `require` everything in your **main** process and whenever the **renderer** process needs a `require`'d module, it communicates to the **main** process via IPC. The response from the **main** process is then sent to the **renderer** process back via IPC.

This is a rough example of how this works

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
    }
  });

  // Load app
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));

  // rest of code..
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
  fs.readFile("path/to/file", (error, data) => {
    // Do something with file contents

    // Send result back to renderer process
    win.webContents.send("fromMain", responseObj);
  });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
            console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
        });
        window.api.send("toMain", "some data");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Disclaimer

I'm the author of [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) which has this pattern built out into a nice starter template, with security practices built in. (This sample was derived from this template).

Answer (score 0):

To require electron this way from a renderer file, you need to double-check the `webPreferences` options of `BrowserWindow` from within the main process js file, it should have those props set to true :

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
//...
    webPreferences: {
      enableRemoteModule: true, // <-- You probably want this but note this is going through a severe deprecation process
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      // ...
    }
});
```