# Launching selenium app from electron require is not defined error

Tags: javascript, selenium, electron

I have created a simple selenium app and now I want it to launch from a gui.

Here is my code

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="selenium.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="align">
      <h1>App</h1>
      <button id="start" class="button is-primary">Start</button>
      
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

selenium.js:

```
startButton.onclick = selenium;

const {Builder, Browser, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function selenium() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get('https://google.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.id("L2AGLb")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("selenium",Key.RETURN);
}
```

I keep on getting
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55908510/16547945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In selenium.js you should delete:

```
startButton.onclick = selenium; // (This is Javascript for the browser)
```

selenium.js is a Node.js file, you can not use in index.html using:

```
<script defer src="selenium.js"></script>
```

[Npm selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

You can not import it, instead you need to use Node.js and to access from the html file to interact with your Selenium code you have to do it from a server like:

- [The native Node.js HTTP](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html)
- [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
- [Fastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify)
- Or others

Express is very easy to use

Comment: How do I import it then? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: I edited my previous answer to answer to your question

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? (Im quite new to node...) ,Thanks

Comment: There are lot of videos in internet available about express, like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe421EPjeBE from 
freeCodeCamp.org called Node.js and Express.js - Full Course
It could be a good starting point to learn about it.

Comment: Ok. But what exactly do I have to implement?

Comment: From your index.html you make a GET request  to the Express server when the Start button is clicked, in the Express route you do the Selenium code.

Comment: You need to start the house from the floor, not from the root, so I recommend you first to learn the basic things before going for more complex.

Comment: So the electron app will have to be bundled with an express server?

Comment: Yes, the electron app need to launch the Express Server, there is a lot of info about how to do it https://www.google.com/search?q=electron+express&rlz=1C5CHFA_enES961ES961&oq=electron+express&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l5j0i7i30l4.1314j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8