# Method is not working in JS with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, require, referenceerror

Require() is not working in script.js file (next to html and css files).

**Are there any alternatives** for .js file next to HTML and CSS

```
async function gen() {
  var child_process = require('child_process');
  child_process.execSync('npm install thealtening-free',{stdio:[0,1,2]});
  
  const bot = await altening.bot();
}
```

Image with error:
[Error: require is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbBZV.png)

Can someone give me an alternative, that would work with HTML/CSS/JS combination

Comment: Are you using cjs? Try *.cjs. Require is a cjs thing (or older node versions). If you use esm standard you don't use require.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with an Electron app I created, this previous answer gave some help.

[Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

#### Edit:

The previous answer didn't really provide much information. I am sorry for that. If you are running Electron JS, possible answers could include changing `nodeIntegration` to true.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });
```

You could also try running `npm install` in your command line, to ensure all packages required by your application are installed correctly.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Or just flag it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are running is only compatible on the server side in NodeJS and similar technologies. There are two pieces to this that you need to understand.

1. **require** is not supported on the web browser. In order to use it, you need a build tool for the web such as [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/). There are a ton of other options, but I like Parcel. It also supports server-side builds and you can create shims for web, etc. for unsupported libraries. Please read up on that.
2. **child_process** is only supported on the server side. It is a `[NodeJS specific library][2]` which means even if you used parcel to build for the web, it won't work unless you use a shim or potentially node emulation.