# Is there a way to use D3.JS in an electron app?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, electron

I am very new to Electron, nodejs and D3 and I am trying to import d3 so I can use it for data visualisation.

My app is running Electron version 22.0.2
NodeJS version 18.12.1
D3 version 7.8.2

I have downloaded d3 using "npm i d3" and whenever I try to use it I get an error saying "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module"

[Here is an screenshot from my main.js file, line 4 is what is giving me an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XprZF.png)

[also here is my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ZZu.png)

I have tried putting type = module in my package.json but that hasn't helped my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're attempting to `require()` d3 in the main process (e.g., inside Node). You need to load it in the renderer process instead (e.g., inside the Chromium window). There are a number of ways you can do this depending on how your Electron app is structured. Simplest would be to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined/57049268#57049268) but checking out other upvoted answers on that page will give other alternatives and a more detailed explanation of why and when alternative methods should be used.