# angular electron app throws path error once tried ipc

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

added these to angular component:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('openModal');
```

added these to main js file of electron

```
ipcMain.on('openModal', (event, arg) => {
        //openModal()
        console.log('abc')
      })
```

it throws require is not defined error. added `declare var require: any` at top of the component. thereafter getting the following error:

```
 node_modules/electron/index.js:2:21:
      2 │ const path = require('path');
        ╵                      ~~~~~~

  The package "path" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
```

Comment: You don't use require in Angular, you use import. Have you tried using it ?

Comment: tried installing packages like `ngx-electron` then imported, and added to imports, but it throws couldn't be used as standalone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: But ignore the accepted answer of the duplicate.