# Unable to import a node addon as ESM module in Electron application

Tags: c++, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to import a simple node addon to an Electron-react application created with electron-vite but I have a conflict with the import of the addon that I have not been able to resolve.

To follow the addon files:

addon/hello.cpp

```
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

void Method (const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
  Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate ();
  args.GetReturnValue ().Set (
      String::NewFromUtf8 (isolate, "world").ToLocalChecked ());
}

void Initialize (Local<Object> exports)
{
  NODE_SET_METHOD (exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE (NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)
```

addon/binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello_addon",
      "sources": ["hello.cpp"]
    }
  ]
}
```

addon/wrapper.js

```
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires: "off" */
let addon

try {
  const addon = require('./build/Release/hello_addon')
} catch (error) {
  console.error('ERROR ON LOAD ADDON')
  console.error(error)
}

export default addon
```

I'm trying to call the addon from the wrapper.js file to the main process in the src/main/index.ts file as follows:

```
...
import addon from '../../addon/wrapper'

function createWindow(): void {

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
    },
  })

  ipcMain.handle('test-addon', async () => {
    console.log('test-node-addon')
    // console.log(addon.hello())

    return addon.hello()
  })

...
```

Then I'm trying to communicate the listener in the preload process via api in the src/preload/index.ts file as follows:

```
...
declare global {
  export interface Window {
    electron: ElectronAPI
    api: typeof api
  }
}

// Custom APIs for renderer
const api = {
  testAddon() {
    return ipcRenderer.invoke('test-addon')
  },
}
...
```

and finally I'm trying to call the addon from a renderer component in
src/renderer/src/components/MainWindow.tsx as follows

```
export function MainWindow() {
 window.api.testAddon().then(console.log)
  return (
    <div className="text-red-600 border">
      Spectrum Analizer
    </div>
  )
}
```

Below is a capture of the error:

[image]

Below a repository link:

https://github.com/juanjacosta/spectrum-analyzer/tree/dev

I appreciate guidance on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks for responding but unfortunately it didn't resolve.

Comment: Please read the other answers and not the accepted one. The error you get is very common.

Comment: I followed the instructions and tried to apply context isolation, keeping the addon require in the wrapper.js file but including the import in main. I also created an ipcMain.on() listener in main to which I pass the call to the addon and a try catch in the wrapper to understand the error but it shows that it cannot find the addon file. OBS: From a simple .js file in the addon folder I can call it but not from electron. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at the code @Arkellys.

Comment: I already took a look at the code. You use `require` in the renderer process, so you get the error. It's what's explained on the duplicate.

Comment: Well, I really removed all `require` for rendering process, and move it for a wrapper.js file that I'm calling in the main process. That's why the error changed to not reading the addon because it's undefined, even though it's defined and the path is correct.