# Importing Ramda in Electron app builded by Rollup leads to error

Tags: javascript, electron, ramda.js, rollupjs, svelte

I'm trying to create a simple app using such stack (snippet from package.json with lib versions):

```
"electron": "^5.0.6"
"ramda": "^0.26.1"
"rollup": "^1.17.0",
"rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.1",
"rollup-plugin-copy-glob": "^0.3.0",
"rollup-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
"rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.1.0",
"svelte": "^3.6.7"
```

and stumbled upon with an issue with importing ramda library: the problem is that if I import ramda in both renderer and main process of electron app, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './chunk-ae261ffc.js'
Require stack:
- <path>/index.html
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (<path>/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:43:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at <path>/dist/renderer.js:3:18
```

My rollup config looks like:

```
export default [
    {
        input: ['src/entries/main.js', 'src/entries/renderer.js'],
        output: {
            dir: 'dist',
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true
        },
        plugins: [
            svelte({
                css: css => {
                    css.write('dist/svelte.css');
                }
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs()
        ],
        external: ['electron', 'child_process', 'fs', 'path', 'url', 'module', 'os']
    }
];
```

I use ramda in root component inside renderer process (App.svelte component):

```
<script>
    import * as R from 'ramda';

    const q = R.always('hello from svelte');
</script>
{q()}
```

and within the entry file of the main process:

```
import * as R from 'ramda';
```

The strangest thing (as for me) is that if I comment any of ramda's import above then no error is thrown. Otherwise, I get the error I described in the beginning of this question

**Upd**

With @ScottSauyet's help, it makes clear that it could be working by replacing `import` with `require`. Yet I don't think it's an appropriate solution (rollup configuration should be changed instead, imho).

Comment: Does this go away if you  do `import {always, ...} from 'ramda'`?  I know some similar bundling issues have for some people.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, unfortunately, it doesn't help. But...it seems to be working with `require`

Comment: I'm just surprised to see that the import statement in your html works at all (i.e. `<script>import * as R from 'ramda'</script>`. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37736836/1244884); I'd recommend using `require()` in your renderer scripts too.

Comment: @customcommander, thanks for you reply and link to question, but I guess it's not related to `import` or `require` usage inside html, because this code snippet is placed in .svelte component transpiled to JS. I'm going to update the question to remove this ambiguity

Comment: It seems like the share chunk `./chunk-ae261ffc.js` does not exists or can not be created. Have you check it in dist folder? imo, i think you should upgrade rollup to the newest version. There's no `experimentalCodeSplitting` and `experimentalDynamicImport` on the newest version. That might the reason why error occurs!

Comment: @CliteTailor, I've just tried to update rollup and remove incorrect properties in config, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: @customcommander: It's not a regular html file, it's a `.svelte` source file, so it will look different after compilation.

Comment: @user1820686 [try this](https://github.com/clitetailor/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/57134084). It works find on my system.

Comment: @CliteTailor, amazing, thanks for the sample. Your code is working on my system too...going to find what's the difference. Seems to be quite identical at first glance

Comment: @CliteTailor, if you would like, you could post your own answer with the fix I suggested as my answer. In that case, I will remove my answer and accept yours. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1820686 Not necessary, your answer is clear enough. You can mark it the right answer. If you like, you can give my github repo 1 star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I greatly appreciate @CliteTailor's effort. This answer, by and large, based on his support.

The problem was in the snippet that I didn't copy to the original question.
I left my `index.html` file in root folder (it's being used in the renderer process) 'as-is' - didn't copy it in `dist` folder with other compiled code and used such link to this file:

```html
<html>
    <!-- some header -->
    <body>
        <script src='./dist/renderer.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

According to @CliteTailor's code, I've just my some changes:

1) added copying of `index.html` to the `dist` folder in `rollup.config.js`:

```
export default [
    {
        input: ['src/entries/main.js', 'src/entries/renderer.js'],
        output: {
            dir: 'dist',
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true
        },
        plugins: [
            svelte({
                css: css => {
                    css.write('dist/svelte.css');
                }
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            copy({
                targets: [{ src: 'index.html', dest: 'dist' }]
            })
        ],
        external: ['electron', 'child_process', 'fs', 'path', 'url', 'module', 'os']
    }
];
```

2) replaced calling this `index.html` from the main file of the renderer process:

```
// old code
win.loadFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'));
// fixed code
win.loadFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

3) changed a link to compiled renderer file in `index.html`:

```html
<html>
    <!-- some header -->
    <body>
        <script src='./renderer.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now everything is working fine.