# Electron: Load a file with `executeJavaScript`

Tags: javascript, electron, browserify, code-injection, npm-package

I need to inject an NPM package into a `BrowserView` by using `executeJavaScript`. The package is [Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/) and here is what I've tried so far.

```
import Web3 from 'web3'

const web3 = '' + Web3; // stringify the Web3 class

view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
  const provider = // ... provider got injected successfully because it doesn't have dependencies.
  const web3 = new ${web3}(provider);
`)
```

But this throws the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: core is not defined
    at new Web3 (<anonymous>:45:5)
    at <anonymous>:41:16
```

Web3 is trying to load its [core dependency](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3/src/index.js#L32) which unfortunately did not get stringified.

So my question is, how can I load this whole package into the `BrowserView`? Aka how can you load npm package in the browser, if you do not have control over `<script />` tags (at least I wouldn't know how to inject those in Electron)?

**Update:**

Because of what OJ Kwon suggested in the comments, I tried bundling Web3 with [Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage) by running

```
browserify packages/web3/src/index.js -o web3-bundle.js
```

. It seemed to have worked, because at the very end of the bundled file (`web3-bundle.js`) it says:

```
// ... 50k+ lines long file

var version = require('../package.json').version;
var core = require('web3-core');
var Eth = require('web3-eth');
var Net = require('web3-net');
var Personal = require('web3-eth-personal');
var Shh = require('web3-shh');
var Bzz = require('web3-bzz');
var utils = require('web3-utils');

var Web3 = function Web3() {
    var _this = this;

    // sets _requestmanager etc
    core.packageInit(this, arguments);

    this.version = version;
    this.utils = utils;

    this.eth = new Eth(this);
    this.shh = new Shh(this);
    this.bzz = new Bzz(this);

    // overwrite package setProvider
    var setProvider = this.setProvider;
    this.setProvider = function (provider, net) {
        setProvider.apply(_this, arguments);

        this.eth.setProvider(provider, net);
        this.shh.setProvider(provider, net);
        this.bzz.setProvider(provider);

        return true;
    };
};

Web3.version = version;
Web3.utils = utils;
Web3.modules = {
    Eth: Eth,
    Net: Net,
    Personal: Personal,
    Shh: Shh,
    Bzz: Bzz
};

core.addProviders(Web3);

module.exports = Web3;
```

Now, I'm trying to import and include it like this:

```
const Web3 = require('./web3-bundle.js');
```

which doesn't work. It says `undefined` is not a constructor.

```
const Web3 = require('./web3-bundle.js').Web3;
```

and

```
const Web3 = require('./web3-bundle.js').default;
```

both didn't work, either. How should one do this?

**Update 2:**
Inspecting the bundle further, it has uses `exports.` and `module.exports =`. My editor only suggests methods and objects exported with `exports.` as importable

Comment: the only way you can do is bundle whole script you need to execute including its dependencies, and executejavascript those bundle as string.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37736836/1244884). It might help or shed some light.

Comment: @OJKwon How would you bundle those and stringify a whole dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this boilerplate or a boilerplate including a good webpack configuration ([suggested boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)).

Follow these steps:

- Clone the repository
- Run `yarn install`
- Run `yarn add web3`
- Add `import Web3 from 'web3';` into the `app/containers/HomePage.js` file (react render view).
- Enjoy