# Electron "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to execute a file with this script:

```html
 <script>
      function verify() {
    var child = require('child_process').execFile;
  var executablePath = "C:\\file";
  
  child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
  if(err){
     console.error(err);
     return;
  }
  
  console.log(data.toString());
    });
  }
    </script>
```

But when I run this script I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".
I've tried to fix this for 3 days with no sucess. I've enabled node intergration, installed browserify and read 10 diferrent explainations on how to do it with no success. Do anybody know a fix for this or a alternative on executing a file?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37736836/1244884) help?

Answer (score 3):

See [the Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes).

You can only use `require` (and use the `child_process` module) from the **main** process, but you are trying to use it from the **renderer** process.

Move it to the main process.

If you need to trigger the function from the renderer process (e.g. when the user clicks on a button) then use [the `ipcRenderer` module](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) to send a message to the main process (and have a listener there which will call the `verify` function in response to that message).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to electron and I'm still learning javascript.

I've this code calling the function in the index.html file: 
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="verify();" />

And the script is now located in the main.js file (which I geuss is the main process?) then ran Browserfy to bundle the script and then changed the src to "bundle.js". Now how do I implement the ipcRenderer module?

Comment: @Sonalk — The Electron website has some great documentation that demonstrates how to use it. I linked to it in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't quite undestand how to use ipcRenderer and I cant find a good video explaining it. I've added "const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain" in the main process file along with the script, how do I use ipc to call that function?

Comment: Again I'm really sorry but I've sucessfully wasted around 15 hours by trying to launch a simple.bat file from a button. I can't understand how that can be so hard to accomplish. I just want a simple explanation so I haven't done all this in vain...

Comment: I don't know what trouble you are having understanding the documentation, so if I were to provide a simple explanation it would be the same as the documentation … which would be pointless.

Comment: All it says in the documentation  is that ipcRenderer and ipc Main are used to send messages between the main process and the renderer process. It doesn't state how to send a message from a button in the process file that activates a function in the main process file. Not that I can see or understand anyway.

Comment: You write a click event listener that calls ipcRenderer to send a message. You set up an ipcMain listener to listen for that message and call execFile.

Comment: Could you maybe create a simple demo I could look at? I've this in the index file:  `function ipcverify(){

ipcRenderer.send('call-verify') 
}` Should I set up a "if" function in the main process? If so how would that code look like?  `If ipcMain.on('call-verify') { code  } `maybe?

Comment: In my index.html I added a btn with an id and linked **ipc.js** which has `const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
window.ipc = window.ipc || {}, function(n) { ipc.messaging = { sendOpenSecondWindowEvent: function() { ipcRenderer.send('open-second-window', 'function')},
init: function() { $('#verifybtn').click( function () { ipc.messaging.sendOpenSecondWindowEvent()   })  } }; n(function() { ipc.messaging.init(); })}(jQuery);` which should link my btn and send msg to main.js in which I've `ipcMain.on('open-second-window', (event, arg)=> { (code)` Am I close?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217105/discussion-between-sonalk-and-quentin).

Comment: Can you help, please? :/